# Returning hours but not minutes

Tags: php, time

I am trying to display time and make calculations afterwards.

```
    <?php
        $totalUd = 0;
        $subTotalUd = 0;
            function convertToTotalUd($totalUd, $format = '%02d:%02d') {
                $subTotalUd = abs($totalUd);
                $hours = intval($subTotalUd % 60);
                $minutes = ($subTotalUd / 60);
                return sprintf((0 <= $totalUd ? '' : '-') . $format, $hours, $minutes);
            }
        $result = mysqli_query($dbcon, "SELECT id, dato, timer FROM content WHERE frihed = 
        'afspadsering'");
            while ($myrow = mysqli_fetch_array ($result)) {
                $dato = "dato";
                $totalUd = $myrow['timer'];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p><?php echo $myrow['dato']; ?></p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <p><?php echo convertToTotalUd($totalUd, $format = '%02d:%02d'); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

The hours are correct but minutes won't return, it says for example 4:00 but should display 4:15 and so on. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some sample data from the database?

Comment: we need sample input, and expected output, and actual output your code is currently giving

Comment: @delboy1978uk I thought I wrote that in the original question. 
The database says for example 4:15, 5:50 and 6:15 but the output is 4:00, 5:00 and 6:00.

Comment: is that a 12 or 24  hour clock time?

Comment: I think it is 24 hour clock time because it displays more than 12 hours when needed, but how is it important for displaying the minutes?